# Use a single SQL Server Database Project for multiple databases

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

we want to start using the SQL Server Database Projects for our databases. The thing is that we have two seperate databases with almost the same table structures, stored procedures, etc. but have a few minor differences. For example one of the two doesn't make use of a few of the tables and does have different users and permissions granted.
What would be a good way to keep the two databases on the same level?
Is it possible to keep just one database project for the two seperate databases and "deactivate" parts on one machine?

If I didn't make clear what I mean:
Image a small Data Warehouse for two stores, with one having table "cars", "motorbikes" and "bikes" but not selling bikes so it makes use of just "cars" and "motorbikes". Is there a way to keep all three tables in the database project but "deactivating" the one table for the second Data Warehouse and Likewise for users, permission, and so on?

Thanks in advance! I literally appretiate all the advice given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a "base project" and then add the differences on top of that base project with a database reference to the base project as "same database, same server" to include all of the shared items. That's probably your easiest way to handle that sort of development. Unless the differences are significant and you shouldn't see those extra tables at all, I don't know that I would go to that effort in most cases, though. Have one schema for everything and just don't use the objects that don't make sense for that particular database.

But if that's not feasible for whatever reason, your best bet is one Solution, one base project, then other DB projects that reference that base project but have their own different objects.  This is usually called a "Composite" project.

The following links may help some to explain that a bit more:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/add-database-reference-dialog-box

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/two-approaches-to-addressing-circular-references-in-ssdt

Comment: Thanks a lot.

I think the changes are a little bit too many to just ignore them, also I haven't found a good way to get GRANTs working on accounts that are supposed to work on just on of the actual databases.

I think this is just the input I need, thanks again, really appreciate it!

Comment: GRANTS - use database roles for those. You'll have a much easier time getting permissions to the roles and then adding the appropriate users to those roles after the fact. Trying to handle all of that inside the project is doable, but _really_ ugly. I have a bit on my blog dealing with that - https://schottsql.com/all-ssdt-articles  ... I don't try to handle users/logins through SSDT anymore if I have a choice. :)

Comment: Don't implement permissions/grants in SSDT. That requires advanced enough knowledge for that. Configure publish profiles to ignore everything related to users and permissions and do them manually or in another way at least for now.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Peter Schott answer. Here is my [repo](https://github.com/dkultasev/SSDTPowerTemplate) where I started to implement my "ideal" SSDT projects template, but never continued and finished ... Anyway, it has everything you need and properly structured already with use of synonyms, publish profiles, deployment from Docker, unit test integration and some other stuff (check Readme).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it!
And for sure I'm going to make use of it!

Comment: @N.M.Spalt appreciation is shown in upvotes in stackoverflow :)

Comment: Thanks again, unfortunately my account is too new to give upvotes yet. I've got one more question if you may: I cloned your git and generate a Deployment script as well as I did a schema compare. And in both cases I see the "dbo.ImportantTable" being added/deployed to the server but for the "dbo.EquallyImportantTable" I only see the CREATE SYNONYM statement but no CREATE TABLE, etc.. Is this supposed to work this way or do you know what I'm doing wrong? (Btw it doesn't make any difference if I set the "include composite objects" option in both cases) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because it is pointing to the table in another project.

Comment: Sorry, I don't recall what's the "include composite objects" and don't have SQL Server and SSDT installed by hand to check